# Hotkeys in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, hotkeys, keydown

Is there a way to create global keys in Silverlight? I added a KeyDown event handler to the topmost Page element. I can catch the key signal when elements like a Button, TextBox, Calendar, and RichTextBox have focus. But the DatePicker won't let me handle the key down event at the Page level. Any way to make a hotkey in non-OOB SL?

P.S. I am assuming that the DatePicker control behaves differently than others as it is still in the Silverlight Toolkit.

Comment: @user246392-Have you get a chance to look into this : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189015%28VS.95%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

have you tried using the [AddHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms598899%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) method? With this method you can add a handler and define if you want to handle already handled events, too.

In my simple example I added it to the RootVisual in the app.xaml.cs.

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            this.RootVisual = new MainPage();
            RootVisual.AddHandler(UIElement.KeyDownEvent, new KeyEventHandler(HandleKeyDown), true);
        }

        private void HandleKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            //Add your keyhandling code here
            Debug.WriteLine(e.Key);
        }
```

I tried it with a DatePicker and it works.

Hope this helps!

BR,

TJ

Comment: Yes - this should work, unless the focus is on a control in a Popup, in which case RootVisual will not get the event.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.pixytech.com/rajnish/2010/05/silverlight-hot-keys/) may help you.  The author provides two ways using HTML bridge (when your Silverlight does not have focus) and using the KeyUp event on [Application.RootVisual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.rootvisual%28VS.95%29.aspx).

I have not tried it myself so I wouldn't know if it's working.